# Kivy ScreenManager root size issue

Tags: python, screen, kivy

I am just trying to set up my menus. I one that looked alright, then I discovered ScreenManager and decided it would be a good thing to use. So I ported my code over to a new file to try it out but the placement of my screen is all out of whack.

What I want:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MainMenu(Widget):
    pass


class G_A_M_E_App(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()

if __name__=='__main__':
    G_A_M_E_App().run()
```

and its .kv file

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<MainMenu>:

FloatLayout:
    width: root.width * 1/3
    height: root.height * 1/2
    center_x: root.width * 1/2
    center_y: root.height * 1/2

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,.5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos



    Button:

        size_hint: (.5, .10)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .90}
        text: 'Play'
        color: [1, 0, 0, 1]

        font_size: self.height * 5/6
        border: [25, 25, 25, 25]



    Button:

        size_hint: (.5, .10)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .70}
        text: 'Load'
        color: [1, 0, 0, 1]

        font_size: self.height * 5/6
        border: [25, 25, 25, 25]


    Button:

        size_hint: (.5, .10)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .50}
        text: 'New Game'
        color: [1, 0, 0, 1]

        font_size: self.height * 5/6
        border: [25, 25, 25, 25]


    Button:
        id: help
        size_hint: (.5, .10)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .30}
        text: 'Help'
        color: [1, 0, 0, 1]

        font_size: self.height * 5/6
        border: [25, 25, 25, 25]
        on_press: root.helpm()


    Button:

        size_hint: (.5, .10)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .10}
        text: 'Quit'
        color: [1, 0, 0, 1]

        font_size: self.height * 5/6
        border: [25, 25, 25, 25]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17JY9.jpg)
and heres the one that doesnt look like that

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class StartMenu(Screen):
    pass

class NewGame(Screen):
    pass

class LoadGame(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass




sm = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class G_A_M_E_App(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
if __name__=='main__':
    G_A_M_E_App().run()
```

and its .kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    StartMenu:
    NewGame:
    LoadGame:

<StartMenu>:
    name: 'start_menu'

    FloatLayout:
        width: root.width * 1/3
        height: root.height * 1/2
        center_x: root.width * 1/2
        center_y: root.height * 1/4

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,0,1,.5
            Rectangle:
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos



        Button:

            size_hint: (.5, .10)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .90}
            text: 'Play'
            color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: self.height * 5/6
            border: [25, 25, 25, 25]



        Button:

            size_hint: (.5, .10)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .70}
            text: 'Load'
            color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: self.height * 5/6
            border: [25, 25, 25, 25]


        Button:

            size_hint: (.5, .10)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .50}
            text: 'New Game'
            color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: self.height * 5/6
            border: [25, 25, 25, 25]


        Button:
            id: help
            size_hint: (.5, .10)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y' : .30}
            text: 'Help'
            color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
            font_size: self.height * 5/6
            border: [25, 25, 25, 25]


<NewGame>:
    name: 'new_game'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'new'
        text: 'New Game'
        font_size: 50

<LoadGame>:
    name: 'load_game'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'load'
        text: 'Load'
        font_size: 50
```

I haven't changed any values for the size I'm still basing it on root and I'm not sure what is affecting it.

[Screenshot of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEuAW.jpg).

Comment: Maybe you could attach a screenshot or two showing what's wrong?

Comment: I added some screen shots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen Manager is a Relative Layout. Here's what's happening.
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy-uix-relativelayout-common-pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your buttons inside a BoxLayout. Like this:

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,.5
        Rectangle:
            size: root.size
            pos: root.pos
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 20
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (.5, .5)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
        Button:
        Button:
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion